# How to limit actions taken with API Token

Tags: javascript, api, access-token

I'm new to programming/development/APIs, so forgive me if I use any terminology incorrectly.

I'm building a simple web app (with JS) that pulls data from a third-party API. The third-party API requires an access token to make all calls.

There are a few different methods to get the token, but [according to the API documentation](https://beta.petexec.net/api/apidoc/index.html#api-Authorization-AuthorizationToken) (and what I've been reading about tokens), I should be using the Implicit Grant type to get a token that requires the user to re-authenticate every hour (or the next time they log-in.)

I'm storing the Access Token in Local Storage whenever I obtain it and use it to make calls to the API accordingly.

The web app is, in theory, *just* supposed to write the authenticated user's data (obtained from the API) to the page. The scope of the token is strictly limited to a property called **owner_read**. (See specific call with permission in the API Docs [here](https://beta.petexec.net/api/apidoc/index.html#api-Profile-GetProfile).)

The issue I'm having is that I realized that the access token generated can be used maliciously. The token generated with the scope of **owner_read** can also be used to make a call to the server and retrieve the data of every customer in the database. (See specific call in the API docs [here](https://beta.petexec.net/api/apidoc/index.html#api-Owner-GetAllOwners).)

This is concerning — I don't want a user to be able to take an access token meant to originally just show a single user's information (the person who is in the web app) and make calls to the server and obtain ALL user data.

My question is: since I cannot limit my scope anymore, how can I prevent the token from being used in other calls?

Comment: do you mean same access token is used to call for other permissions/apis?

Comment: if so then its a problem from server side access control Please check [rbac](https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/role-based-access-control-RBAC)

Comment: Yes. With the third-party API in question, there's no differentiator between an admin-level scope and a user-level scope, so an end-user (who shouldn't be able to access any info other than their own) can, in theory, access ALL the information that an admin can with the token generated.